# Devise config.secret_key only needed in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting this error on our NEW staging when the config.secret_key is not set in devise.rb, but it works in development environment without setting it, is that intend? So only development not requiring config.secret_key?

For some reason our OLD staging worked fine as well without config.secret_key, any idea?

```
 Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

 config.secret_key = '22b6bad239151c217c9c10d34328e4350d7c90ed8b4a3fcf593835c2f54bf4f7b6044df52e262f667e673eddb1ccd73e606b345acdf0f1d5f0abf62863ed5f18'

 Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says:

Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

config.secret_key = '-- secret key --'

Answer (score 0):

**Devise Secret Key**

Devise uses secret key for security. In development mode it doesn't require secret key but in production mode. You have to set a secret key in config/initializer/devise.rb